# Hyperlinks not working after preview?

Tags: hyperref

I have used `hyperlinks` throughout my thesis, but then after previewing the pdf output and saving it for printing, the links are gone. Any idea why this occurred?

Here's a working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}              
\geometry{letterpaper}                   
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
%
\begin{document}
\href{http://www.google.com}{Google} %
\end{document}
```

Comment: No problem here compiling your minimal example. It shows coloured text 'Google' that links to the proper address when clicked. When you say "..., the links are gone.", are you saying that the word disappears ('Google' in this case) or the embedded hyperlink ('http://www.google.com' in this case)?

Comment: @Werner Grundlingh: The links work after compilation, but when you safe the file as pdf, it ceases to work.

Comment: What is the original file type that you save it from - DVI? If this is the case, I would suggest following the `latex->dvips->epstopdf` sequence or `pdflatex` rather than saving a DVI as a PDF.

Comment: @Werner Grundlingh: The same pdf. If you save the output of the working example above, and then tries to click on the link, you'll find it won't work.

Comment: What previewer do you use? Preview? Is it on a Mac? What PDF viewer do you use? Adobe Acrobat/Reader?

Comment: This sounds like a PDF viewer issue, not a LaTeX issue.

Comment: @BrettHarry: Your MWE works for me after compiling it with `pdflatex` directly to a PDF. Please tell use which compiler and other software you are using. Otherwise it's basically impossible to help you.

Comment: @Werner Grundlingh, You, & Martin Scharrer: I use pdflatex as well and the output is pdf. The problem occur only when i resave the **Thesis.pdf** file again with a different name. E.g. **Myname_mysurname.pdf**, and I do this saving after print preview in Mac.

Comment: I think this is your problem - (Print) *Preview* on a Mac does not support hyperlinks. See [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1883602?start=0&tstart=0). Here's the suggestion, instead of saving a print preview (from within *Preview*), rename the original **Thesis.pdf** to **Myname_mysurname.pdf** and then recompile **Thesis.tex**.

Comment: @Werner: Please turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is your problem - (Print) *Preview* on a Mac does not support hyperlinks. See [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1883602?start=0&tstart=0). Here's the suggestion, instead of saving a print preview (from within *Preview*), rename the original **Thesis.pdf** to **Myname_mysurname.pdf** and then recompile **Thesis.tex**.